# How to write a function to map points on a canvas to points on the real plane

Tags: python, pygame, fractals, complex-numbers

I'm writing a simple Mandelbrot visualiser in Python onto a pygame Screen. For each pixel on the 600 by 600 Screen, I am plotting whether or not this pixel, (x, y) as a complex number, is in the Mandelbrot set or not.

The problem being that I start at (0, 0) and iterate through to (600, 600), most of which is outside the set anyways. So I chuck in a scaling factor to zoom in, but I'm still only plotting the upper right quadrant. I would like some way of making it so my plot was always centered around 0+0i.

What I would like to do is find some kind of way to map the 600px^2 canvas to the real plane from [-2, 2] on the x-axis to [2, -2] on the y-axis. This would mean for instance, that the complex number 0+0i would map to (300, 300) on the screen. This way, my plot would always be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a window for your data. You know it is 600 pixels wide and 600 pixels tall. The pixel coordinates are  (0, 0) - (600, 600). You can do this:

```
Point coordFromPixelLocation (pixelX, pixelY, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, minCoordX, maxCoordX, minCoordY, maxCoordY)
{
    xPercent = pixelX / pixelWidth;
    yPercent = pixelY / pixelHeight;

    newX = minCoordX + (maxCoordX - minCoordX) * xPercent;
    newY = minCoordY + (maxCoordY - minCoordY) * yPercent;

    return Point (newX, newY);
}
```

pixelX and pixelY are the pixel coordinates that you want to convert to the smaller range. pixelWidth and height are the width and height of your window. min/maxCoordX/Y are the (-2,-2) to (2,2) values.

Comment: But do be careful in python!  It is very likely that people will send in integers, and your division will get brutally rounded down.  You should explicitly convert the numerators into floats if you want to try this.  (also call it xFraction, it is really a percentage).   Also this will actually produce the range -2 .. +1.993333, which is probably close enough.

Comment: `from __future__ import division`?

Answer (score 1):

In truth I would take a more flexible approach, and write your code to allow fairly arbitrary mappings, but to do literally what you ask, you can try:

```
x = (float(pix_x) + 0.5 - 300.0) / 150.0
```

and then the same of `y`.  This treats each pixel as being a point at the centre of the-on-screen pair, but maps the *corners* of the pixels to (+-2, +-2).  This is the most "correct" way to map whole of your viewport to the whole of the square in the complex plane, but one downside of this is that you will never plot some important numbers, such as the 0, the real line or the imaginary line.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mapper:
    def __init__(self, old_ul, old_lr, new_ul, new_lr):
        self.old_ul = old_ul
        self.old_lr = old_lr
        self.new_ul = new_ul
        self.new_lr = new_lr
        self.old_diff = Point(old_lr.x - old_ul.x,
                              old_ul.y - old_lr.y)
        self.new_diff = Point(new_lr.x - new_ul.x,
                              new_ul.y - new_lr.y)

    def map(self, pt):
        nx = (self.old_lr.x+pt.x) * (self.new_diff.x / self.old_diff.x) + self.new_ul.x
        ny = (self.old_ul.y+pt.y) * (self.new_diff.y / self.old_diff.y) + self.new_lr.y
        return Point(nx, ny)
def main(args):
    pixelToReal = Mapper(Point(0, 0), Point(600, 600), Point(-2, 2), Point(2, -2))
    realToPixel = Mapper(Point(-2, 2), Point(2, -2), Point(0, 0), Point(600, 600))
    print(pixelToReal.map(Point(300,300))) # prints 0.0,0.0
    print(realToPixel.map(pixelToReal.map(Point(300,300)))) # prints 300,300
    for x in range(0,630, 30):
        for y in range(0,630, 30):
            print(pixelToReal.map(Point(x,y)))
```

Mapper's constructor takes the original upper left and lower right corners, and the new upper left and lower right corners.  Mapper.map() converts a point from the original space to the new one.